# How to clip scene to screen bounds?

Tags: ios, ios5, cocos2d-iphone

I have a scene, containing layers which are large enough to be off-screen. When I do scene transition (eg. `CCTransitionSlideInR`) the off-screen part is visible during transition which of course looks ugly. What I want is to clip the scene to screen size. How can I do that?

Comment: which cocos version? I vaguely remember there was a  fix in 2.1 related to that issue

Comment: 2.0. I've tried with scissors. It does indeed clip on-screen region, but it doesn't clip off-screen region...

Comment: try upgrading to 2.1 rc1 then

Comment: It's explosive to upgrade stable project to rc :) If you know the patch that addresses the issue, or the issue itself, it would also be helpful.

Comment: unless you're 2 weeks before release, it's absolutely no big deal. "Stable" and "beta" are very relative terms, and specifically for cocos2d. It's not like non-stable builds are somehow unstable, or stable builds devoid of any issues. ;)  You can always try the upgrade in a copy of the project, and give it a good test drive.

Comment: Anyway, the class provided in answer works. I just had to add each layer that required clipping to the clippingNode object, and then add it to scene. Before I just tried to implement glScissors inside -visit method of my scene, which failed.

Comment: In a pinch, I've added black/white CCLayerColor's on whatever sides you want to clip, of winSize.width. Worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could perhaps use this:

https://github.com/njt1982/ClippingNode

The main page references original sources.